# Custom announcement list saving DOM elements to html file

Tags: 2010, javascript, html

I'm using a content editor web part to place a `<ul>`, which I'm using to display my Announcements. I'm using the [SPServices](https://spservices.codeplex.com/) js library to append each announcement from my Sharepoint announcements list to the `<ul>` as a new `<li>`. This is working fine except for when a user deletes an item from the announcements list, the item remains in my `<ul>`.

This "kinda" makes sense as I don't have a mechanism to delete each item but looking at my code, I thought I was only appending each item to the DOM? That leads me to my first question.

Edit: I can observe that DOM elements are being saved when I open the web page (Home.aspx) in SharePoint Designer and each announcement has made it's way into the markup.

1) When i append a `<li>` to my `<ul>` why is it being saved to the file and not just the DOM?

2) Is there an elegant way to delete and item from my `<ul>` once it has been deleted from my announcements list?

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getAnnouncments, "sp.js");

function getAnnouncments()
{        
    var operation = "GetListItems"; 
    var list = "Announcements";       
    var fields = "<ViewFields>" +
                            "<FieldRef Name='Title' />" +   
                            "<FieldRef Name='Id' />" +
                        "</ViewFields>";                                   
    var query = "<Query>" +
                    "<OrderBy>" + 
                        "<FieldRef Name='Created' Ascending='TRUE'/>" +
                    "</OrderBy>" +
                "</Query>";

$().SPServices(
{
    operation: operation,
    webURL: "Removed...",
    async: false,
    listName: list,
    CAMLViewFields: fields,
    CAMLQuery: query,                     
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) 
    {        
        var currentListItems = []; // Array to hold all current items in my <ul>
        var getItems = $("#announcementsList li").get(); // Get all items in my <ul>

        $.each(getItems, function(){
            currentListItems.push(item.innerText); // Append each <li> innrtext text to my array.
        });         

        $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() 
        {             
            var title = ($(this).attr("ows_Title"));
            var id = ($(this).attr("ows_ID"));      
            if ($.inArray(title, currentListItems) == -1) // My sad attempt to prevent duplicates in my <ul>. Only a problem because DOM elements are being saved to the html file. 
            {                                       
                addRowToList(title, id);                                                                                    
            }
        }); 

        $('.open_announcement').click(function()
        {       
            var args = this.getAttribute('data-args');
            var options = {url: args, height: 1000, width: 850, allowMaximize: true, showClose: true, };
            SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);        
        });
    }
});
}

function addRowToList(title, id)
{
    var url = "Removed" + id;
    var html = "<li><a href='#' class='open_announcement' data-args=" + url + ">" + title + "</a></li>";
    $("#announcementsList").append(html);                                
}
```